# How do I parallelize writing a list of Pyspark dataframes across all worker nodes?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing, aws-glue, distributed-system

I have a basic AWS Glue 4.0 Job I'm trying to run that runs a transform function and returns a list of dataframes:

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from transform import transform
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from datetime import datetime

# ========================================== CONTEXT INITIALIZATION ====================================================
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv)

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
# ======================================================================================================================



pyspark_df_list = transform(inputs)


// NOT SURE what to do here to achieve parallelization

# ======================================================================================================================

job.commit()
```

**Things I've tried:**

1. Iterating through the list seems to break the paralleization and essentially makes the write operations single-threaded.
2. Creating a `write_df` function and trying to call the `parallelize/forEach` function off the SpaceContext gives me the following error:

RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

Comment: May be an idea to look at the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are parallelizing the individual dataframe.

1. In Scala you can use `.par`. That said, it depends on your resource allocation mode used with Resource Manager, e.g. YARN.
2. You can write N Spark Apps as alternative.
3. Or you can have multiple independent (N) `Actions` in a single Spark App, with N arrays. For both SCALA and pyspark.
4. For pyspark you can use `ThreadPoolExecutor`. See https://gist.github.com/pavel-filatov/87a68dd621546b9cac1e0d2ea269705f. An excellent explanation on .par equivalent in pyspark.

I am not sure I would go down latter or .par approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce`/`unionAllByName` to create a single DataFrame and then write that. If that still doesn't achieve the degree of parallelism you require, user `repartition` to create more partitions in your data (1 partition = 1 worker process during write):

```
from functools import reduce

df = reduce(lambda x,y: x.unionAllByName(y), pyspark_df_list)

df.write.repartition(128).format(....
```